# strcpy_s not showing debug assertion failed in Visual Studio

Tags: c, debugging, assertion

This simple C program just exists without any notification.
How to enable debug assertion notification in Visual Studio 2022?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str1[5] = { 0 };

    errno_t errn = strcpy_s(str1, 5, "xxxxxx");
    printf("err %d\n", errn);
    printf("str %s \n", str1);
}
```

**Edit**:
I edited the code. Pasted wrong string before.

Comment: Why do you expect an assertion ? `"chuj"` fits well into `str1`. Try a longer string like `"chuj123"` to trigger the assertion (and in Debug mode only).

Comment: Sorry, I pasted wrong code. It was supposed to be `errno_t errn = strcpy_s(str1, 5, "xxxxxx");` it still does not throw any assertion.

Comment: Why do you include `<windows.h>`, `<stdint.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`? Try removing these include files.

Comment: Can you post the program output?

Comment: There is no output at all, program exists without any notification from strcpy_s. Removing header files you mentioned before also did not change a thing.

Comment: Can you run the program in a terminal window from the shell prompt? There is a chance Visual Studio does not catch the runtime error.

Comment: Compiled your updated code as is in VS2022 (in _Debug_), and when I ran it I got the assertion popup message:  "Expression:  (L"Buffer is too small" && 0)", as expected. Are you sure you compiled in Debug config ?

Comment: Ok. I finally managed to find why this happened to my solution. I changed Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> All Options -> Runtimne Library to Multi-threaded Debug DLL and it finally worked. The solution was configured as Debug but that simple option still prevented me to use Debug mode